# Dual axis chart y-axis values customizing

Tags: highcharts

"Am using dual Y-axis chart.That chart contain +v'e and -v'e values. can i set both y-axis values range based on our values(which are coming from database)?"
"In Image the chart positive and negative values range taken as same. but negative values range not have that much. so, i need to restrict that range as near actual value"

Comment: Hi K.Satya, Could you describe more precisely what result do you want to get?

Comment: thank you for your response. am implementing dual Y-axis  chart.That chart contain both positive and negative values. but negative values range not that much. it take same range of postive y-axis range defaultly. is it possible to restrict that range similor like actual values?Below is my data and JsFiddle link

http://jsfiddle.net/7bwrhko2/1/

Comment: Hi K.Satya, Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/h0ejmp7o/ Do you want to achieve something like that?